# getting this error -> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at com.raghuvamsha.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

in my program:
1. Main Class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

    // Using Scanner for Getting Input from User
    System.out.println("\tMAIN MENU:\n" +
            "\t\t1) Add new member record\n" +
            "\t\t2) Modify existing member record\n" +
            "\t\t3) Delete member record\n" +
            "\t\t4) Display all member records\n" +
            "\t\t5) Search for a particular member record\n" +
            "\t\t6) Exit");

    int a = 0;
    while(a!=6) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        a = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered integer " + a);

        if(a==1){
            AddNewMember anm = new AddNewMember();
            anm.openFile();
            anm.addRecords();
            anm.closeFile();
        }
    }

   }
}
```

2. AddNewMember Class.

   public class AddNewMember {

   private FileWriter x;
   private Formatter form;

   public void openFile(){

   ```
   try{
       x = new FileWriter("/Users/askeladd/Downloads/animals.dat", true);
       form = new Formatter(x);
   }

   catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println("You have an error");
   }
   ```

   }

   public void addRecords(){

   ```
   //Adding Animal Name.
   System.out.println("Please input animal name: ");
   Scanner reader_an = new Scanner(System.in);
   String animal_name = reader_an.next();

   //Adding Animal's Owner.
   System.out.println("Please input animal's owner Name: \n");
   System.out.println("First Name: ");
   Scanner reader_aofn = new Scanner(System.in);
   String animal_ofn = reader_aofn.next();

   System.out.println("Last Name: ");
   Scanner reader_aoln = new Scanner(System.in);
   String animal_oln = reader_aoln.next();

   //Adding species.
   System.out.println("Please input animal species: ");
   Scanner reader_s = new Scanner(System.in);
   String animal_s = reader_s.next();

   //Adding Date of Birth.
   System.out.println("Please input animal Date of Birth: ");
   Scanner reader_dob = new Scanner(System.in);
   String animal_dob = reader_dob.next();

   //Adding Treatments
   List<String> animal_treatments = new ArrayList<String>();
   System.out.println("Please input treatments: ");

   int i = 0;
   Scanner reader_treatments = new Scanner(System.in);
   while (i<10) {


       String s = reader_treatments.next();
       if (s.equals("q")|| s.equals("Q")) {

           break;
       }
       animal_treatments.add(s);

       i += 1;

   }
   System.out.println(animal_treatments);
   ```

   }

   public void closeFile(){
       form.close();
   }

   }

I have read some posts in StackOverflow regarding the issue, it was mentioned to use next() instead of nextLine() in my code, but still it was not working. Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: don't use next, use nextLine and you'll be ok for all (until you know exactly what each does) nextLine() it the easiest

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but I wouldn't instantiate the `Scanner` inside a loop, I'd do it once before the loop. Saves a lot of overhead

Comment: @IsaacAbramowitz If that isn't the problem, I'll be quite surprised.

Comment: @chrylis I mean, it's A problem, but I haven't tested it so I'm not sure if that's the issue leading to askeladd's problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Upshot

First, you shouldn't be creating multiple instances of `Scanner`.  But your main problem is that ***you aren't doing error checking on the input that the user is giving you***.  The `InputMismatchException` was probably thrown beacause you entered something other than an integer on the menu.  Try this code to fix it:

---

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here

        // Using Scanner for Getting Input from User
        int a = 0;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (a != 6) {
            System.out.println("\tMAIN MENU:\n" +
                    "\t\t1) Add new member record\n" +
                    "\t\t2) Modify existing member record\n" +
                    "\t\t3) Delete member record\n" +
                    "\t\t4) Display all member records\n" +
                    "\t\t5) Search for a particular member record\n" +
                    "\t\t6) Exit");
            boolean intValid = false;
            while(!intValid) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid option (1 - 6).");
                String input = reader.next();
                if (isInteger(input)) {
                    a = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    if (a >= 1 && a <= 6) {
                        intValid = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("You entered integer " + a);

            if (a == 1) {
                AddNewMember anm = new AddNewMember(reader);
                anm.openFile();
                anm.addRecords();
                anm.closeFile();
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isInteger(String str) {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+");
    }
}
```

**AddNewMember.java**

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Formatter;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.List;

public class AddNewMember {

    private FileWriter x;
    private Formatter form;
    private Scanner reader;

    public AddNewMember(Scanner reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            x = new FileWriter("/Users/askeladd/Downloads/animals.dat", true);
            form = new Formatter(x);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You have an error");
        }
    }

    public void addRecords() {      
        //Adding Animal Name.
        System.out.println("Please input animal name: ");
        String animal_name = reader.next();
        //Adding Animal's Owner.
        System.out.println("Please input animal's owner Name: \n");
        System.out.println("First Name: ");
        String animal_ofn = reader.next();

        System.out.println("Last Name: ");
        String animal_oln = reader.next();

        //Adding species.
        System.out.println("Please input animal species: ");
        String animal_s = reader.next();

        //Adding Date of Birth.
        System.out.println("Please input animal Date of Birth: ");
        String animal_dob = reader.next();

        //Adding Treatments
        List <String> animal_treatments = new ArrayList <String>();
        System.out.println("Please input treatments: ");

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            String s = reader.next();
            if (s.equals("q") || s.equals("Q")) {
                break;
            }
            animal_treatments.add(s);
            i += 1;
        }
        System.out.println(animal_treatments);

        reader.close();
    }

    public void closeFile() {
        form.close();
    }

}
```

---

### A Side Note

I don't know if this is for a school project of something you are making on your own, but if you really want to handle user input with a nice interface, take a look at [Java Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html).

Also, you will have to do a lot more error checking on the input fields for the input in `AddNewMember` if you don't want similar errors in the future.

**Happy Coding!**